# centering numbers in round buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

i created a round border button that shows some numbers in it. 
I tried to center the numbers in the different buttons, but  text-align and vertical-align could not help to center the number in every dimension (vertical and horizontal).

Can you please help me to achieve that goal?

here is my code:
http://jsbin.com/nefuhukuja/edit?html,css,output

Thank you

EDIT: 
I also got problems to do this with the text below the buttons

Here is CSS

```
.minus
{
text-align:center;
}
.countdown-overlay .col-lg-2 p{
color: #cfd8dc;
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.btn span{
color: #cfd8dc;
font-size: 70px;
}

.btn-circle{
border: 7px solid #cfd8dc;
border-radius: 130px;
font-size: 12px;
height: 130px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
padding: 10px 0;
width: 130px;
text-align: middle;

}
.btn-circle.btn-lg{
border: 7px solid #cfd8dc;
border-radius: 130px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 18px;
height: 130px;
line-height: 1.33;
padding: 10px 16px;
width: 130px;
vertical-align: center;
}
.btn-circle.btn-xl{
border: 7px solid #cfd8dc;
border-radius: 130px;
font-size: 24px;
height: 130px;
line-height: 1.33;
padding: 10px 16px;
width: 130px;
vertical-align: center;
}
button .minus{
text-align: center;
margin:auto;
vertical-align: center;

 }
.btn-circle span{
vertical-align: center;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.countdown-overlay{
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
text-align: center;
 }
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {

button.btn.btn-circle.btn-lg
{
    height:70px;
    width:70px;
    border-radius:70px;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding-right:25px;
    margin-left:-10px;

}

button .minus
{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-size:30px;

}

}
```

Here is HTML and script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">      </script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row countdown-overlay" style="z-index:2">
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
     <script src="js/countdown.js"></script>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg">    <span class="minus" id="day">-</span></button>
        <p>days</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg">    <span class="minus" id="hour">-</span></button>
        <p>hours</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg">    <span class="minus" id="minute">-</span></button>
        <p>minutes</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg">   <span class="minus" id="second">-</span></button>
        <p>seconds</p>
     </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code help must include enough code **in the question** to reproduce the issue. Links, while helpful, would be of no use to future SO users should the link become non-functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is `padding-right`. You must remove `padding-right` for your **class:**  `button.btn.btn-circle.btn-lg` inside your `@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {...}`.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/y2aqys0r/) out.

You are forcing the content to left inside by giving `padding-right`

**Update:**

The above solution solves your issue for only if you have two digits in a circular div. If you want more to cover(Like 3 digits: xxx).
You either need to try among following:

**1)** Increase dimensions for circle (class: `.button.btn.btn-circle.btn-lg`)

Or

**2)** Decrease the font-size for `.minus` class/div.

No other alternative i guess is more suitable.